# Is nesting regexes ever necessary?

Tags: java, regex

I want to pull out the two numbers 10 and 11 from HTML that looks similar to this, only it has even more noise than what I show here:

```
<div a>
<noise=53>
<item=10>
<item=11>
</div>
<div b>
<item=20>
<noise=52>
<item=21>
</div>
```

I have figured out how to do it by using two regexes: first use

```
(?s)(?<=<div a>).*?(?=</div>)
```

to get stuff in the "div a" section, then use

```
(?s)(?<=<item=)[0-9]*
```

on the result to get the numbers I want. But I can't figure out how to do it in only one regex. I have a guess about how I could if only Java let me put *s in lookbehinds, but Java doesn't (and I vaguely understand why not). Is it possible to do this with only one regex or should I settle for two?

Comment: Why aren't you using an XML parser? Pretty sure there must be an easy way to do this "properly" in Java!

Comment: That is not XML. And if it is in your application, use an XML parser instead of regular expressions.

Comment: Sorry for the misuse of terminology; I had always thought HTML counted as a kind of XML. I will look into using HTML parsers, but since I have already implemented it with a Regex I'd still appreciate seeing how my code could be fixed.

Comment: @divider: this is also **not remotely HTML**.

Comment: @Matt Ball: "looks similar". I'm afraid I don't see how the problem would be significantly different if my example were real HTML.

Comment: Technically, HTML is a form of SGML, and XHTML is a form of XML.

Comment: @divider: `<item>` and `<noise>` aren't valid HTML tags in any HTML spec that I am aware of; and you've opened tags without properly closing them. Maybe you could post your actual HTML (or "HTML"?).

Comment: @Matt Ball: "looks similar". I agree what I posted isn't real HTML. If you are trying to help and must see the actual HTML, I can post it, but I suspect that's not what's going on here.

Comment: @Kathy Van Stone: Technically technically, HTML was a form of SGML before HTML 5.  In HTML 5, there is an XML syntax ("XHTML5") and an HTML syntax ("HTML5"), but not an SGML syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not completely certain what you mean by nesting regexes. The way this sort of thing is usually approached is to carefully pull off just a bit at a time, like a lexer.  That way you don’t have to try to build everything into one pattern.

Instead of using `Matcher.matches()`, you might go at it by using `Matcher.lookingat()`, which looks for something from the current start point.  That way you could test for a bunch of them from the same position.

A similar tactic involves using the one-argument form of `Matcher.find()`, where you supply a starting character position as the argument.

A related feature is the `\G` anchor, a zero-width assertion that makes the search start up just where the last match on that same string left off. It saves you some bookkeeping that way.

By combining judicious uses of the `find(N)` and `lookingat()` methods (plus `start()`),  perhaps with the `\G` assertion, you can build yourself a more flexible and sophisticated processing algorithm than is  practicable using  a single regular expression alone.

It really is a lot easier to use structural logic with regular Java managing your regexes for the pieces than it is to try to do everything in one gargantuan regex.  It’s much easier to develop, debug, and unit-test that way, too. Regexes work best at dealing with pieces of strings, not trying to encode an entire parsing algorithm in them.

Plus in Java you can’t really do that anyway, since there’s no support for recursion within the pattern. Perhaps it’s just as well, because it encourages you to put the control structures in the outer language, since you can’t always put all of what you’d need in the inner one.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can get down to one. But note that pulling apart HTML is best done with an XML or HTML parser.  YOu can use an XML parser if the HTML is well-formed XHTML; otherwise look at http://java-source.net/open-source/html-parsers.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String s = "<div x><item=02><noise=99><item=05></div>\n" + 
        "<div a><noise=53><item=10><item=11><noise=55><item=12></div>\n" + 
        "<item=99>\n" + 
        "<div b><item=20><noise=52><item=21></div>";
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println();
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(
        "(?:<div a>|\\G)(?:[^<]++|<(?!(?:item|/?div)\\b))*+<item=(\\d+)");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find())
    {
      System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
  }
}
```

output:

```
<div x><item=02><noise=99><item=05></div>
<div a><noise=53><item=10><item=11><noise=55><item=12></div>
<item=99>
<div b><item=20><noise=52><item=21></div>

10
11
12
```

Breaking that down, we have:

- `(?:<div a>|\\G)` : `\G` matches wherever the previous match left off, or at the beginning of the text if there was no previous match.  It's prevented from matching at the beginning by the lookahead in the next part, so the first match starts at the `<div a>`.
- `(?:[^<]++|<(?!(?:item|/?div)\\b))*+` : This part consumes whatever lies between the current match position and the next `<item=N>` tag.  It gobbles up all characters except `<`, and `<` if it's not the beginning of a `<item`, `<div`, or `</div` sequence.  (The latter two ensure that all `<item=N>` matches are contained within the same `div` element; additionally, `<div` is what prevents `\G` from matching at the beginning of the text, and `</div` prevents matches *between* `div` elements, like `<item=99>` in the example.)
- Finally, `<item=(\\d+)` matches the `item` tag and captures the number you're after.

Answer (score 0):

I think the **Sed** utility would be more useful than programming with regular expression to extract the text data.
Try following script in [Sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/index.html)(with option **-n**).

```
/<div \w>/,/<\/div>/ {
    s/.*item=\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/p
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is real HTML it can be converted to XML, e.g. by HTMLTidy or NekoHTML, and then you should use an XPath expression on it.

Answer (score 0):

Don"t even try, you need a parser, many are avaible.